# Why won't local-site theme update on iPadOS Safari?

Tags: themes

I am running WordPress on MAMP.

I am making theme changes, but they are not appearing in iPadOS Safari.

Only Private mode shows the latest. Chrome iOS also does.
I am not running any caching plugin.

Things I have done:

- Hard-refreshed Safari.
- In Settings>Advanced for Safari, I cannot see any clearable data for the local site (and I don't really want to clear *all* browsing data).
- Checked any caching settings for MAMP, I don't think there are any.
- I've included a $ver number in wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script, too.

I'm running the blankslate theme, but injecting Bootstrap into it. So, functions.php has `require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/enqueue.php';`, which contains:

```
<?php
function load_bootstrap()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha3-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), null, false); // In <head>
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha3-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array(), null, true); // Footer before </body>
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_bootstrap');
```

Now, those files are getting inserted into the necessary places in the HTML source, and the files can be accessed directly in the web browser. But the rendered page just still looks like plain blankslate.